# Non Raid - Symbolic links

Tags: raid, nas, lvm, mdadm, zfs

I have 3x 3TB drives and 2x 1TB drives.

I want to use all drives without RAID, but to be shown as a single volume.
So that if a drive fails only the information on that failed drive will be lost.
Then in turn that drive can be replace with either a smaller or larger drive expanding or contracting the volume. 
I do not care about redundancy.

Linux.

What can I do?

Comment: why not use RAID?

Answer (score 0):

Mount each drive separately, and use these mount points for writes in order to send files to particular drives. Then, use `aufs` to union mount all of your mount points together:

```
mount -t aufs -o dirs=/mnt1:/mnt2 none /union_mnt
```

`/union_mnt` gives you read access to all drives.